# Folder not showing up showing up with `ls`

Tags: command-line, directory

I have a folder I can `cd` into by simply using `cd /path`. However, when I use `ls`, the folder doesn't show up, and it's not hidden, meaning that `ls -a` doesn't make it appear, either. What could account for this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post some actual terminal output?

Comment: I’m wondering if this is simply that cd /path is an absolute path, whereas ls will show the contents of your current working directory?

Comment: try `ls /` and tell us if it is there

Comment: @user10489 yes that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unix filesystem isn't one big huge directory.  There is a heirarchy that starts from `/`.   When you first log in, you are put in your home directory which is probably something like `/home/username`.

If you can get to something with `cd /path` then `ls` isn't going to show it unless you `cd /` first or `ls /`.

You might find the documentation offered by the command `man path_resolution` enlightening.